# same date to be one date and want to be average temperature @one day in php

Tags: php, date

Following is my php code:

```
<?php 
  echo "<h1>test</h1>";
  echo "<table border = '1' width = '50%'>\n";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>date</th>";
  echo "<th>temperature</th>";


  //get data from file
  $fileName = 'sensor.csv';
  $file = fopen($fileName,"r");


  //while not to end of file
  while (!feof($file) ) 
  {

    while (($csv_line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
    {

      $date_format = strtotime($csv_line[0]);
      //print_r($csv_line);
      echo "<tr>";    //beginning new row of record
      echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d", $date_format)."</td>";  
      echo "<td>" . $csv_line[2]."</td>";  
      echo "</tr>"; //new row

    }
    echo "</table>\n";
  }

?>
```

---

The following is the current output

```
date        temperature
2015-07-20  22.7
2015-07-20  22.7
2015-07-20  22.8
2015-07-19  32.8
2015-07-19  31.9
2015-07-19  32.8
2015-07-19  32.8
2015-07-18  29.1
2015-07-18  28.8
2015-07-18  29.7
2015-07-18  29.9
2015-07-18  29.4
2015-07-18  29.8
2015-07-16  26.4
2015-07-16  25.9
2015-07-16  24.7
2015-07-16  24.9
2015-07-16  25
2015-07-16  26.4
2015-07-16  27
2015-07-16  26.1
2015-07-16  26
```

I want it to be like this:

```
date        temperature
2015-07-20  average temperature of each day
2015-07-19  average temperature of each day
2015-07-18  average temperature of each day
2015-07-16  average temperature of each day
```

Comment: Perhaps look into `array_sum();` - [php.net/array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: Thanks, But It's not like that

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT date, AVG(temperature) as AvgTemp
FROM TableName
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: now date have right. But AVG('temperature') is not work in mysql

Comment: try removing single quotes

Comment: Please try to avoid posting answers with suggestions that might solve a problem. Ideally post answers that you can verify will address the issue. Also it's always helpful to explain how your proposal will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code, it might contain errors since I could not check it

```
<?php

echo "<h1>test</h1>";
echo "<table border = '1' width = '50%'>\n";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>date</th>";
echo "<th>temperature</th>";


//get data from file
$fileName = 'sensor.csv';
$file = fopen($fileName,"r");


while (!feof($file)) {

    $cs = fgetcsv($file);
    $last_date = $cs[0][0];
    $sum_temp = 0;
    $count = 0;
    $csv_line = array();
    $firsttime = true;

    do  {
        if (!$firsttime) {
            $date_format = strtotime($csv_line[0]);
            $temp = $csv_line[2];
        } else {
            $date_format = $last_date;
            $temp = $cs[0][2];
        }

        if ($date_format == $last_date) {
            $sum_temp += $temp; // Combine tempratures
            $count++;
        } else {
            $avg_temp = $sum_temp / $count; // Get the average temprature

            echo "<tr>";    //beginning new row of record
            echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d", $last_date) ."</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $avg_temp ."</td>";  
            echo "</tr>"; //new row

            $sum_temp = 0;
            $count = 0;
        }
        $firsttime = false;
        $last_date = $date_format;
    } while(($csv_line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE);

    echo "</table>\n";

}

?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: csv_line in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 28

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 31

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 31

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 31

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 31

Comment: Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 37

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 37

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\array_combine.php on line 37

Comment: soory this my first output

date        temperature
2015/07/20  22.7
2015/07/20  22.7
2015/07/20  22.8
2015/07/19  32.8
2015/07/19  31.9
2015/07/19  32.8
2015/07/19  32.8
2015/07/18  29.1
2015/07/18  28.8
2015/07/18  29.7
2015/07/18  29.9
2015/07/18  29.4
2015/07/18  29.8
2015/07/16  26.4
2015/07/16  25.9
2015/07/16  24.7
2015/07/16  24.9
2015/07/16  25
2015/07/16  26.4
2015/07/16  27
2015/07/16  26.1
2015/07/16  26

Comment: @nainglinhtut check it now

Comment: now your code is right but it's not include last date and last date of temperature and also i dont want to first line in csv file. bocz this is the title heading thanks

Comment: average temperate is not right. something is wrong.

Comment: @nainglinhtut can you put the contents of `sensor.csv` file?

Comment: now this process is happening following

date                 time        temp
2015/7/20 23:45 20
2015/7/20 23:30 30
2015/7/20 23:15 40
2015/7/19 23:00 20
2015/7/19 22:45 40
2015/7/19 22:30 10
2015/7/18 22:15 23.3
2015/7/18 22:00 23.4
2015/7/18 21:45 23.7

for example above is data in sensor.csv file including file path. so it will out put 

date               average_temp
2015-7-20 30
2015-7-19 23.33
2015-7-18 real_average_temp


but now it will be like that

date               average_temp
1970-01-01      1
2015-7-20 40
2015-7-19 not_sure_temperature
2015-7-18 not_sure_temperature